# How represent block of text with regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use C# go parse out text using a known pattern. I have the following text

```
Fn.StartIf(some condition) 

Block of blob text. This text could start with a new line or it may not... This text could be anything including numbers and special characters number like 123.

and it multiple lines of text and could end with a new line or not. 
Fn.EndIf
```

At the end, I want to get the following groups:

1. (Group 1) Fn.StartIf(some condition)
2. (Group 2) some condition
3. (Group 3) all the text in between
4. (Group 4) Fn.EndIf

Here is what I have tried `(Fn.StartIf\((.+)\))^(.+|\n*|\s*)$(Fn.EndIf)`. But, the pattern `^(.+|\n*|\s*)$` is not grabbing all the blob text follow `Fn.StartIf(some condition)` and before `Fn.EndIf`

How can I correctly grab all the blob text between `Fn.StartIf(some condition)` and before `Fn.EndIf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```regex
(Fn\.StartIf\((.+?)\))([\S\s]+)(Fn\.EndIf)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iYJ54n/1).

A few things to notice:

- `.` matches *any* character. You should use `\.` in order to match a literal dot.
- Use a lazy match inside the parentheses (`.+?`) to avoid matching nested parentheses (if found).
- To match any character (including whitespace characters), you may use `[\S\s]`.

#### C# example:

```
string input = "Fn.StartIf(some condition) \n\nBlock of blob text. This text could start with a new line or it may not... This text could be anything including numbers and special characters number like 123.\n\nand it multiple lines of text and could end with a new line or not. \n\nFn.EndIf";

string pattern = @"(Fn\.StartIf\((.+?)\))([\S\s]+)(Fn\.EndIf)";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

if (match != null)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= match.Groups.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Group #{i}: {match.Groups[i].Value}");
    }
}
```